# Break down a bibliography in Context according to category of item

Tags: context

A requirement for a memoir that I am typesetting (for a friend), using Context, is to separate the bibliography into several sections according to the category of the item (textbook, legal text, etc.). My friend has a bibtex file (using JabRef).

I haven't been able to find an answer in the MkIV-publications manual or the Context wiki, nor did a google search (including this website) yield  anything usable.

Any hints or ideas (or even code!) ?

I am also familiar with biblatex, which I think can perform this breakdown, so a way to make Context use a biblatex file would be good also.

Comment: I don't think this is possible in the current setup.  What you could do, is put each category in a separate file to define a separate btxdataset for each, because you *can* filter by dataset.